# Consumer expenditure survey about food consumption

Tags: survey

I'm confused about the data source about food consumption from the consumer expenditure survey. I find the survey data from the CES website, https://www.bls.gov/cex/pumd_data.htm#sas.

Comment: Hi @Carl, have you tried searching the documentation from that site?  There seems to be plenty of it.

Comment: Hi, might you send me a link to it? I'll have a try! I want to find individual data. Many thanks!